# String replace first occurrence only with a word from an array in php

Tags: php

```
$needle = array("Arr","Arr:","Arrang");
$haystack = " Arr is the proper way of Arr.";
echo str_replace($needle, "Arrangement", $haystack);
```

Prints: `Arrangement is the proper way of Arrangement`

Want: `Arrangement is the proper way of Arr.`

Comment: This even shows `Arrangementement is the proper way of Arrangementement`

Comment: How do you choose which word to replace with?

Answer (score 3):

Use `preg_replace` with an `implode` and delimiter for your array. The delimiter `\s|` acts as an `or` statement with the regex pattern that your array creates:

```
$needle = array("Arr","Arr:","Arrang");
$haystack = "Arr: is the proper way of Arr.";
echo preg_replace("/".implode("\s|",$needle)."\s/", "Arrangement ", $haystack, 1);
```

**Result**:

```
Arrangement is the proper way of Arr.
```

Comment: if `$haystack = "Arr is the proper way of Arr:";`, still output shows `Arrangement is the proper way of Arr.`

Comment: @SubinThomas thats what is being looked for isnt it?

Comment: need `"Arr","Arr:","Arrang"` all these to be replaced, I think @Rich

Comment: Yep, so we only do it once, and Arr gets found first over Arr: and Arrang., because its a shorter string.

Comment: @Octopi : Still need clarity of question. Not clear his needs.

Answer (score 2):

Try `preg_replace`. The 1 here means match on the first instance only. `/string/` searches for the string.

```
$haystack = "Arr is the proper way of Arr.";
echo preg_replace("/Arr/", "Arrangement", $haystack, 1);
```